# Listar unidades del disco C#

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo listar las unidades del disco en C#?

Sé que en Java es:

```
import java.util.io;
String [ ] unidades = File.listRoot();
```

> SALIDA:
>  C:\
>  D:\

¿Como puedo obtener esto en C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La solucion es sencilla: `DriveInfo` es la clase que te ayudara

Agrega los nombres de espacio a la clase:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

en tu metodo:

```
 DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
    {
        string label = drive.IsReady ?
            String.Format( " - {0}", drive.VolumeLabel ) : null;
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} - {1}{2}", drive.Name, drive.DriveType, label );
    }
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
//getInfoDrives
    C: – Fixed – Win10
    D: – Fixed – Data
    E: – USB
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)